# Create WordPress posts with links under /blog

Tags: wordpress

My current set-up results in posts being created under the webroot:

- www.domain.com/my-post
- www.domain.com/my-other-post

How can I make it so posts are created "under" `/blog/`:

- www.domain.com/blog/my-post
- www.domain.com/blog/my-other/post

Editing the permalink results in the `/` needed being turned into a `-`.

Is there a setting the force posts under a parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As at WordPress 5.2.2, in `Settings` > `Permalinks`, in the `Common Settings` section, the option to set a custom structure for permalinks exists for posts.

The default is set to Plain, which results in `/?p=123` style posts. Switching to Custom Structure allows the switch from the default of `/%postname%` to `/blog/%postname%`.

My existing posts now live under `/blog/` along with newly created ones.

As a side note, if the site is already live then redirects might be needed if you have post links out in the wild.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ plugin and just add blog in url before post name,it will work

Comment: Thanks Bijal. I had a look and that plugin tells you to check in `Settings` > `Permalinks` to make sure the baked-in functionality doesn't already exist. Turns out it does!